# How to use one SQLAlchemy Engine te create one Database connection for each process?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing, pool

I'm migrating a sql database to a Postgres Database. I would like to take avantage of the COPY keyword and multiprocess.

I manage to achieve this by creating one SQLAlchemy Engine for each process.
I had to use a raw_connection to be able to use copy_from().

I guess it would be better to create only one Engine and one connection for each process.
But so far I can't.

If I create one SQL connection and one Postgres engine for each process it works:

```
SQL_COS = [pyodbc.connect(SQL_ADDR) for _ in range(NB_CPU)] 
PG_COS = [create_engine(PG_ADDR) for _ in range(NB_CPU)]

def migration(table, statement, i):
    result = SQL_COS[i].execute(statement)

    rows = StringIO()
    while (row := result.fetchone()):
        line = [x.hex() if isinstance(x, bytes) else str(x).replace('\r', '\\r') for x in row]
        rows.write('\t'.join(line) + '\n')
    rows.seek(0)

    pg_co = PGCOS[i].raw_connection()
    with pg_co.cursor() as pg_cursor:
        pg_cursor.copy_from(rows, table, null='None', columns=(c[0].lower() for c in result.description))
    pg_co.commit()
    pg_co.close()

statements = create_statements() # bunch of SELECT * FROM TABLE
pool = Pool(processes=NB_CPU)
for i, statement in enumerate(statements):
   pool.apply_async(migration, args=(*statement, i % NB_CPU)) 
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

But as soon as I try to create one Postgres raw_connection for each process I have errors:

`ERROR:  unexpected message type 0x51 during COPY from stdin`
`FATAL:  terminating connection because protocol synchronization was lost`
`WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress`
`WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress`

I tried to use pooling option with the engine creation (AsyncAdaptedQueuePool and SingletonThreadPool) but I feel like I misundertood something else entirely.